# Spyder not running after upgrade

Tags: python, spyder

my spyder won't run after I upgraded it. How do I restore previous version in ubunutu? Don't have anaconda platform so conda command isn't an option. Tried to uninstall/install but nothing happens.

Thanks a lot of your help,

newbie

Comment: Does it throw any error message? How did you uninstall it, from Ubuntu Software Centre?

Comment: No it just won't run. I click on the icon and it shows like its starting but nothing happens. NO error message no nothing. I tried to uninstall with sudo pip uninstall spyder and tried to reinstall it and it just starts to a starting icon and then crashes.

Comment: I uninstalled it now but every time I try to reinstall it it crashes.

Comment: After uninstalling you may want to remove any leftover files/directories related to spyder such as configuration files - `/home/USERNAME/.spyder2/.spyder.ini`

Comment: Try `spyder --reset` and/or `spyder --new-instance` in the terminal

Comment: tried not working. Tried to install it with ubuntu software and pip and conda, every time i run it it crashes instantly. bwaaaaaaah.

Comment: Okay spyder 3 is working but it automatically jumps in to python 3.5 which I dont want. I need 2.7 for job reasons. Tried to changing  it in tools-preferences but it doesnt work. Any other idea how to switch?

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) If you really are a *Noob programmer*, please switch to use Anaconda, conda and the conda envs instead of fighting with pip, which is much harder to make it work correctly. Other than that, I refrain from giving you further help because you don't want to accept this simple piece of advice, which we mention time and time again.

Comment: I am on anaconda now. it is working :) thanks!